# How to set proper data source for report when i first time deploy that report to report server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have a problem when i first time deploy a new report to Report server(SSRS) , report doesn't have correct data source. Problem is in ReportServer database.
I can manually set data source to that report after report is deployed, but i want to set data source(shared data source) in time of deployment.

Does anybody has a solution for this?
I this the best way is to have some sql upgrade script for this, but i don't how to do it

Comment: Are you using a shared datasource in the designer as well? if not, there's your problem.

Comment: Yes i use Shared data source in VS project for this. Problem is in database, i can see the new report but it doesn't have any data source set

Comment: when you deploy your report for the 1st time; you have to set from Shared Data source. subsequent deployments (provided you keep report name same, data source SHOULD NOT HAVE TO BE RE-SET) . Sadly no way around 1st time setting it in both deployment modes (i.e. Sharepoint and SSRS Native).

Comment: go into your report server. make sure to hit details at the home screen if you have to to view hidden folders. And there is a folder named [Shared Connections]. You can create new connections there to various envrionments or dbs. And then deploy the report to desired folder. Once report is deployed hit the drop down and select properties. 1st tab is data source. Select the desired global data source you set in step 1. Any default params. And your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create Shared datasource in project in SSDT, then design and create report. You could deploy the entire project in report server, then the datasource will also be deployed on it

Zoe